# Can gulp-freemarker be used in a gulp build to address what fmpp.tools.AntTask does in an ant build?

Tags: ant, gulp, polymer, fmpp

new here, so I hope this question is adequate.

We have a an ant build file that runs a task to preprocess html template files.  Here is the snippet from the build file.

```
        <!-- Process the templates. -->
    <fmpp sourceroot="on-board" outputroot="${template.dir}" removeExtensions="TMPL" >
     <include name="**/*.TMPL" />
      <data expandProperties="true">
       DEBUG: true
       CONTENT_REVISION: r${Revision}
       CONTENT_PACK: vzw-${TRACK}
      </data>
    </fmpp>
```

I am working with polymer now and want to convert our build to use gulp because fmpp (and yuicompressor) are choking on some of the js files in polymer due to reserved words.  I found a gulp-freemarker plugin that I thought might be able to substitute for fmpp.  However, 1) I am not sure of this, and 2) I can not seem to get anything working with gulp-freemarker including their example code from github.

Here is my gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var freemarker = require("gulp-freemarker");

gulp.task('myfmpp', function() 
{
  return gulp.src("./app/en_US/hello.json")
  .pipe(freemarker(
  {
     viewRoot: "app/en_US/",
     options: {}
   }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest("./www"))
});
```

This seems to run OK - no errors - but there is no apparent output.  Since I am a bit new to this stuff, I may not know what I should be looking for...

Anyway, my ultimate goal is to achieve the same preprocessing result from gulp-freemarker as with ant/fmpp.  Can anyone help answer this and point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

- Ken

Comment: This might just be a copy&paste error from when you wrote your question, but `pipe(freemarker(` is missing a dot. Should be `.pipe(freemarker(`.

Comment: Yep, C&P error.  I fixed it and thanks!

Comment: What are the mentioned problematic reserved words? I'm asking because both FMPP and, presumably, gulp-freemarker uses the same syntax for the templates.

Comment: Sorry, had some PTO and got shuffled to another task for a while.  Some of the reserved words I think I remember as being an issue are instanceof and import.